# Ruby on Rails check the datatype length limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails App and I am using an EachValidator method to check the length of the attribute and showing the error according to limit

the validation goes like this

```
validates :name, :presence => {
      :message => 'Please enter name'
  }, :string => self.columns_hash["name"].type
```

now in the `:string` custom Validation I am right now passing the datatype of the name column, but i want to pass the datatype length instead. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: sorry, what is a datatype length?

Comment: I meant to say the character limit. like for string it is 255

Comment: @user4965201 do you mean mysql?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Try `columns_hash['name'].limit`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```
 validates :name, :presence => {
          :message => 'Please enter name'
          }, :length => {
                  :maximum => columns_hash['name'].limit
              }
```

Let me know if it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :name, :presence => {
          :message => 'Please enter name'
          }, :length => { maximum: 255 } # 255 for a string data type
```

Comment: i wanted to access the existing datatype limit which is stored in the sql table

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you, there is a gem available for this:

```
gem 'validates_lengths_from_database'
```

Then in your model simply put:

```
validates_lengths_from_database
```

Which will generate validations based on the schema for maximum lengths of string and text fields.

Comment: i got an error of my sql , when i changed the varchar(255) to varchar(6) from database and entered a value more than 6 , got no error message from this gem

Comment: hmmm, interesting, this does throw validation errors for me, I have been using this on multiple projects with no issue. If I get a chance I shall experiment later - how did you change the length of the field?